# Remove values from columns that meet simultaneous DataFrame pandas condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Be the following DataFrame in pandas.

| country | ctry | city | cty | other | important | other_important | other_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | France | París | París | blue | 019210 | 0011119 | red |
| Spain | Spain | Madrid | Barcelona | blue | 1211 | 0019210 | blue |
| Germany | Spain | Barcelona | Barcelona | white | 019210 | 1212 | red |
| France | UK | Bourdeux | London | blue | 019210 | 91021 | red |

I have to fill with NaN the information of the unimportant columns (other) in case `country != ctry || city != cty`. Dataframe result:

| country | ctry | city | cty | other | important | other_important | other_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | France | París | París | blue | 019210 | 0011119 | red |
| Spain | Spain | Madrid | Barcelona | NaN | 1211 | 0019210 | NaN |
| Germany | Spain | Barcelona | Barcelona | NaN | 019210 | 1212 | NaN |
| France | UK | Bourdeux | London | NaN | 019210 | 91021 | NaN |

Finally I delete the country and city columns.

```
    df = df.drop(['country', 'city'], axis=1)
```

| ctry | cty | other | important | other_important | other_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | París | blue | 019210 | 0011119 | red |
| Spain | Barcelona | NaN | 1211 | 0019210 | NaN |
| Spain | Barcelona | NaN | 019210 | 1212 | NaN |
| UK | London | NaN | 019210 | 91021 | NaN |

I would be grateful if the columns that I want to leave as NaN, could be indicated in a string vector with the name of each one. `['other', 'other_1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with set misisng value by conditions:

```
cols = ['other','other_1']
df.loc[df.country.ne(df.ctry) | df.city.ne(df.cty), cols] = np.nan
df = df.drop(['country', 'city'], axis=1)
```

Solution with remove columns `country, city` use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
cols = ['other','other_1']
df.loc[df.pop('country').ne(df.ctry) | df.pop('city').ne(df.cty), cols] = np.nan
print (df)
     ctry        cty other  important  other_important other_1
0  France      París  blue      19210            11119     red
1   Spain  Barcelona   NaN       1211            19210     NaN
2   Spain  Barcelona   NaN      19210             1212     NaN
3      UK     London   NaN      19210            91021     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# list of columns
cols=['other', 'other_1']

# use mask to make NaN when condition is met
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df['country'].ne(df['ctry']) | df['city'].ne(df['cty']))

# drop columns
df = df.drop(['country', 'city'], axis=1)
df
```

```
    ctry    cty         other   important   other_important     other_1
0   France  París       blue    19210       11119               red
1   Spain   Barcelona   NaN     1211        19210               NaN
2   Spain   Barcelona   NaN     19210        1212               NaN
3   UK      London      NaN     19210       91021               fNaN
```